# MEAN: GETting an array of usernames

Tags: angular, express

I have a User-Schema in my backend, which has a username property. I now want to get a string[] of every username available.

my GET query returns an Observable. I can log the array to the console, and it will contain the correct names, but I can't figure out how to turn this Observable into a string array that I can work with in Angular.

```
router.get('/names', auth, function(req, res, next){
  User.find(function(err, users){
    if(err) { return next(err); }
    res.json(users.map(user => user.username));
  });
})


var mongoose = require('mongoose');

let UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, lowercase: true, 
        unique: true, required : true }, // unique username
    hash: String, // no passwords in cleartext
    salt: String // add salt to protect against rainbow attacks
});
```

I presume I'm doing it wrong... any ideas?

Comment: So are you having trouble getting the names into an array on the backend side that you can then send to the frontend or do you have trouble getting the array inside your angular app after making your request?

Comment: provide your angular code.

Comment: In my frontend, I'm requesting the data as follows `getUserNames() { return this.http .get(`${this._appUrl}/users/names`) .forEach(val => console.log(val)); }`. I was trying to use a forEach, which didn't work, but I realized that I'm getting an array object, to which I can have indexed access.